# Sql error says "incorrect syntax "="

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In this sql I just want to check in "ON" clause b.block='False'.Because sometime "profileview " table values are empty.
I just want ,If user_fullinfo values matches in profileview with this condition b.block='False' It should be display,If values are not there in profile view then also it should be display,

```
SELECT  a.* FROM user_fullinfo a left join profileview b on
CASE
WHEN a.id=b.rid and b.rid='105' THEN 
b.block='False' 
END
where gender != 'Male' and (DATEDIFF(YY,dob,GETDATE()) Between '10' and '100') and (a.heightid between 58 and 65) and( a.complexionid = '3' or a.complexionid = '4' or a.complexionid = '5') and a.bodytypeid = '4' and a.marital_statusid = '3'
```

it says sql error (102) :incorrect syntax near "="..
Please give solution..

Comment: And why is `mysql` tagged here?

Comment: The statement is mysql-syntax, not recognized my sql server

Comment: Where is join condition?

Comment: i got answer below thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean expressions are not suitable as values, such as the value for a `case`.  My advice is to remove the `case` entirely and just use boolean logic.  Something like this:

```
select a.*
from user_fullinfo a left join
     profileview b
     on (a.id = b.rid and b.rid = '105' and b.block = 'False') or 
        ( not (a.id = b.rid and b.rid = '105' and b.block = 'False') and
          gender <> 'Male' and (datediff(year, dob, getdate()) Between 10 and 100) and
          (a.heightid between 58 and 65) and
          (a.complexionid in (3, 4, 5)) and
          a.bodytypeid = 4 and a.marital_statusid = 3
        );
```

Notes:

- The standard for SQL inequality in SQL is `<>`, although `!=` is also widely accepted.
- Don't use single quotes around numeric constants.  `between '10' and '100'` is not the same as `between 10 and 100`.
- I doubt that this version or your `case` version really does what you want.  There is no correlated between the two tables for the second condition.

This should solve your *syntax* problems.  The logical problem is a different issue.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with sample data, desired, results, and an explanation of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Sine you have only 1 condition in the case statement, you can use the direct join instead like below

```
SELECT  
    a.* 
    FROM user_fullinfo a 
        LEFT JOIN profileview b 
            ON a.id = b.rid 
                AND b.rid ='105' 
                AND b.block ='False' 
        WHERE gender <> 'Male' 
            AND (DATEDIFF(YY,dob,GETDATE()) BETWEEN '10' AND '100') 
            AND (a.heightid between 58 and 65) 
            AND 
            (
                a.complexionid = '3' 
                OR 
                a.complexionid = '4' 
                OR 
                a.complexionid = '5'
            ) 
            AND a.bodytypeid = '4' 
            AND a.marital_statusid = '3'
```

in case you have any other case statements you need to add you may change the ON statements like this

```
ON 
(
  (
     a.id = b.rid 
     AND b.rid ='105' 
     AND b.block ='False' 
  )
  OR
  (
     a.id = b.rid 
     AND b.rid ='105' 
     AND b.block ='True' 
  )
)
```